# Условные операторы в WHERE mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть коннект:

```
$uConnect2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid != 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
```

Также присутствует условие:

```
WHERE uid != '1'
```

Как например добавить ещё 4 условия(uid != 2, uid != 3 и т.д)? с and работает только 2, а как сделать несколько? Может есть решение проще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid NOT IN (1,2,3,4) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
```

Comment: вообще не оч хорошо писать ORDER BY RAND(). посмотрите здесь например: http://habrahabr.ru/post/54176/

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE uid != 1 AND uid !=2 AND uid !=3 ....

// advanced style

WHERE uid NOT IN (1,2,3,...)
```